# Codeigniter 4: Merge arrays then use InsertBatch to insert data in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into MySQL using the 'InsertBatch' function. However, I am unable to make it work. I'm new to this, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

I'm using input and select fields with `$is data` and a table with `$tmp data`. I used `foreach` and `for` statements to get the `$tmp_data` on the table. An `array push()` was also used to merge the data into an array.

```
public function Add_Fees_Matrix() {

        $fm_model = new Mod_Fees_Matrix();
        $data = [];

        //input and select type
        $is_data = [
          'fm_code' => $this->request->getPost('fm_code'),
          'sy_id' => $this->request->getPost('sy_id'),
          'dept_id' => $this->request->getPost('dept'),
          'gl_id' => $this->request->getPost('gl_id'),
          'ppl_id' => $this->request->getPost('ppl_mode')
        ];

        //table
        $tmp_data = [
          'fcp_description' => $_POST['fcp_description'],
          'fmf_amount' => $_POST['fmf_amount']
        ];


        foreach ($tmp_data as $k => $v) {
          for($i = 0; $i < count($v);$i++) {
              array_push($data, $is_data);
              $data[$i][$k] = $v[$i];
          }
        }

      echo "<pre>";
      var_export($data);

      $fm_model->insertBatch($data);
      
    }
```

In my output, it generates four arrays. However, only the first two arrays are considered necessary. I think the problem is caused by the `array push()` function.

Here's the output of `var_export()`:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'fm_code' => 'FM-1741195162687292',
    'sy_id' => '2',
    'dept_id' => '1',
    'gl_id' => '2',
    'ppl_id' => '1',
    'fcp_description' => 'INSTITUTIONAL DEVELOPMENT FEE',
    'fmf_amount' => '123',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'fm_code' => 'FM-1741195162687292',
    'sy_id' => '2',
    'dept_id' => '1',
    'gl_id' => '2',
    'ppl_id' => '1',
    'fcp_description' => 'MATRICULATION',
    'fmf_amount' => '1230',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'fm_code' => 'FM-1741195162687292',
    'sy_id' => '2',
    'dept_id' => '1',
    'gl_id' => '2',
    'ppl_id' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'fm_code' => 'FM-1741195162687292',
    'sy_id' => '2',
    'dept_id' => '1',
    'gl_id' => '2',
    'ppl_id' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Upon clicking a button, can someone help me to insert the data on my database?

Comment: I'm trying to piece together the problem. Is the output you show from the `print_r` function? If you can articulate why only the first two are "necessary" and the other are not, you will also articulate how to filter `data`

Comment: @Jerry yes, the output is from the `print_r` function. The first two are necessary because I only need to insert two data item. However, it may vary depending on how many data are in the category. I need to insert rows based on the number of `fcp_description` and `fmf_amount` values.

Comment: Assuming we are looking at your controller, we should not see CodeIgniter's insertBatch() method called from the controller -- it should be called from the model. It is not the controller's job to interact with the database. We should not see `$_POST` being directly accessed in a CodeIgniter application -- use its native methods only.  Why is your html being populated with Javascript (client-side)? Is the data not coming from the server-side (PHP)?

Comment: Your nested loop seems to be the source of the problem.  This doesn't look to be specific to CodeIgniter at all.  Please remove all of the html, screenshot, and excess variable declarations.  All that we need to see is your original/raw input data from the posted submission (ideally what is printed from `var_export()`, then we need to see your exact desired output array. Then we can very easily advise you on how to reach this new data structure in the most direct fashion.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, the html is populated with the JavaScript. I use JS to load the `fcp_description` from the database. As I searched online, all I can see is the `insertBatch()` is in the Controller that's why I put it there. I already change the output using the `var_export()`. And yes, I think the nested loop is my problem since I tried it using a real data array in the `$data` and it worked.

Comment: The `var_export()` is your current output? or the `var_export()` is the raw POST payload that needs to be filtered?  I'm asking for the raw POST payload.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in my problem.

```
public function Add_Fees_Matrix() {

        $fm_model = new Mod_Fees_Matrix();
        $data = [];

        $tmp_data = [
          'fcp_description' => $this->request->getPost('fcp_description'),
          'fcp_amount' => $this->request->getPost('fmf_amount')
        ];

        foreach ($tmp_data as $k => $v) {
          for($i = 0; $i < count($v);$i++) {
              $data[$i]['fm_code'] = $this->request->getPost('fm_code');
              $data[$i]['sy_id'] = $this->request->getPost('sy_id');
              $data[$i]['dept_id'] = $this->request->getPost('dept');
              $data[$i]['gl_id'] = $this->request->getPost('gl_id');
              $data[$i]['ppl_id'] = $this->request->getPost('ppl_mode');
              $data[$i][$k] = $v[$i];
          }


        }

      $fm_model->insertBatch($data);

      echo "<pre>";
      var_export($data);
    }
```